# Maven remove resource from dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a `jgroups` dependency which has a `log4j2.xml` in its JAR which is getting picked up by `log4j` instead of my config file.

How can I get Maven to exclude this file from the JAR dependencies?

...before its suggested, I can't use the system property to set the log4j2.xml file explicitly as I want to be able to start my project without setting any JVM variables in the IDE.

Comment: I think you're going to have to re-package the dependency jar file.  That being said, you might be able to do it on the fly with something like the [trueZIP plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Where do you have the problem picking up the wrong configuration file? Within tests?

Answer (score 0):

The shade plugin can exclude specific files - see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html). Also I'd try if having your config file before the unwanted one on the classpath would make log4j pick yours up.
Also according to the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) log4j2-test.xml and log4j2.json on the classpath have precedence over log4j2.xml unless log4j.configurationFile system property is set, which btw you can also do from maven, so you don't have to set anything in your IDE.